# Optimizing simple query

Tags: mysql, optimization

This query will show you all of the unread topics in a given forum.  The output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` was a bit alarming.  I'm wondering if someone here can provide some insight into how I can optimize.

```
SELECT topic.*
FROM topic
INNER JOIN board ON topic.board_id = board.id OR topic.board_id = board.mirror_board_id
INNER JOIN category ON board.category_id = category.id
INNER JOIN group_assoc
 ON (
  group_assoc.board_id = board.id AND
  group_assoc.group_id IN (4,15,18,22) AND
  group_assoc.viewable = 1
 )
WHERE topic.last_post_time > 1288278402
AND category.forum_id = 2
AND board.id NOT IN(4,3)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM topic_read_assoc
    WHERE topic_id = topic.id
    AND member_id = 332
)
ORDER BY topic.last_post_time DESC
```

output:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 PRIMARY category ref PRIMARY,forum_id_2 forum_id_2 4 const 5 100.00 Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY board ref PRIMARY,mirror_board_id,category_id_2 category_id_2 4 source_forum.category.id 4 100.00 Using where
1 PRIMARY group_assoc ref board_id,board_id_2,board_id_3 board_id_3 4 source_forum.board.id 4 100.00 Using where; Using index
1 PRIMARY topic ALL board_id_2 NULL NULL NULL 2462 100.00 Range checked for each record (index map: 0x4)
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY topic_read_assoc ref topic_id topic_id 8 source_forum.topic.id,const 1 100.00 Using index
```

Comment: yea . really simple query. :)

Comment: @zod: why, it fits on screen, both vertically and horizontally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use EXISTS for the group_assoc table, use an inner join on board for it (which is in effect happening anyway with "WHERE board_id = board.id". Put the filtering info. in the WHERE clause.

The same goes for topic_read_assoc - use an inner join on topic ON topic_id = topic.id.

Also, this is just to make it easier, you can use the IN syntax for Board.id so it's only one line like this:

WHERE ... board.id NOT IN (3,4)

EDIT> As Quassnoi rightly pointed out below, simply adding inner joins will cause duplicates.  So use DISTINCT or GROUP BY what you want to see.  The query should not be using SELECT * anyway by the way.  If a column is added to that table, your code could be broken (not in the query itself, but by what is done with the results).

Comment: EXISTS is not bad per se, but a JOIN will perform better in most cases.

Comment: @Konerak: which cases exactly?

Comment: Putting the tables in the JOIN will make it easier for the optimizer to do its majic. Also, EXISTS is not bad in and of itself, but a JOIN will be easier to read and make the more consistent (since all of the WHERE statement will be to limit the results instead of joining tables).

Comment: @Mark: given that the subquery can return multiple values, how do you rewrite it as a join?

Comment: @Quassnoi, since the subquery (or EXISTS statement) is already functioning as a join, it will limit the records, but not to just one record (unless it was doing that already anyway).

Comment: @Mark: sorry, I'm not getting you. "Since the subquery is already functioning as a join" — what does it mean?

Comment: @Quassnoi, Because the EXISTS is in the WHERE clause, it is limiting the results already, right?  The query is forced to include only the records, for instance, in group_assoc WHERE board_id = board.id (and other limitations).

Comment: @Mark: right, it is limiting the results. Now, the question was "how do you rewrite it as a join"?

Comment: @Quassnoi,  Simple, INNER JOIN group_assoc ga ON ga.board_id = board.id. But put the rest of the WHERE Clause in the main where clause.

Comment: @Mark: You'll get duplicates in this case.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I don't think there will be duplicates since the query is not showing results from that table.

Comment: I've rewritten the query per your suggestions Mark, it's looking good.  Though with `INNER JOIN topic_read_assoc ON topic_read_assoc.member_id !=` will it still work when there's a row for each member who's read this specific topic?  It'll join anyways because there's an entry for another member...

Comment: @Mark: you think wrong. The presence or absence of the fields in the `SELECT` lists has no effect on the number of records and values of the other fields. If the subquery returns, say, `4` records for a certain `topic_id`, then you'll get `4` duplicates of this `topic_id` in your resultset if you rewrite it as a `JOIN`.

Comment: @Quassnoi, you're right.  I suppose that I'm so used to grouping that it doens't often affect me.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: @Mark: do you really think `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` will be more efficient than `EXISTS`?

Comment: @Quassnoi, yes it should.  I avoid EXISTS and IN whenever possible.

Comment: @Mark: again, what's bad in `EXISTS` and `IN`?

Comment: @Quassnoi, you can disagree with me, my experience is that EXISTS and INs are slower.  Also, the query has been edited, but I believe that it wasn't consistent with itself (excludiung and including the same value in different places).  So part of this is for us humans.

Comment: @Mark: With properly indexed tables, `IN` and `EXISTS` are much faster than a `JOIN` with `GROUP BY`. They only are slower when written improperly or when the tables are not indexed correctly. Here, the subqueries are written correctly and the tables are indexed properly and you can see quite an efficient plan for them in the `EXPLAIN` output. The query was consistent before editing (you can see it in the history of the post edit).

Answer (score 2):

Create an index on `topic (last_post_time)`.

You can also remove `LIMIT 1` from the `EXISTS` subquery, it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

this would be my query for showing all unread topics in a forum

```
select * from forum_topic where forum_id = 1 and num_views = 0;
```

simple example follows:

```
-- TABLES

drop table if exists forum;
create table forum
(
forum_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
title varchar(255) unique not null,
num_topics int unsigned not null default 0
)engine=innodb;


drop table if exists forum_topic;
create table forum_topic
(
topic_id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
forum_id int unsigned not null,
subject varchar(255) unique not null,
num_views int unsigned not null default 0,
num_replies int unsigned not null default 0,
key (forum_id)
)engine=innodb;

delimiter #

create trigger forum_topic_after_ins_trig after insert on forum_topic
for each row
begin
 update forum set num_topics=num_topics+1 where forum_id = new.forum_id;
end#

delimiter ;

-- STORED PROCEDURES

drop procedure if exists get_forum_topic;

delimiter #

create procedure get_forum_topic
(
in p_topic_id int unsigned
)
begin
    update forum_topic set num_views=num_views+1 where topic_id = p_topic_id;
    select * from forum_topic where topic_id = p_topic_id;
end #

delimiter ;

-- TEST DATA

insert into forum (title) values ('forum1'),('forum2');

insert into forum_topic (forum_id, subject) values 
(1,'forum 1 topic 1'), (1,'forum 1 topic 2'),
(2,'forum 2 topic 1'), (2,'forum 2 topic 2');

-- TESTING 

call get_forum_topic(1);
call get_forum_topic(3);
call get_forum_topic(2);
call get_forum_topic(3);
call get_forum_topic(2);
call get_forum_topic(3);

select * from forum;
select * from forum_topic;

select * from forum_topic where num_views = 0;
```

Comment: I'd prefer to stick with a basic query and not venture into views, triggers, or procedures

Comment: i'll repeat the BASIC query for you again "select * from forum_topic where forum_id = 1 and num_views = 0" how you manage to implement this i.e using a counter field plus sprocs and tiggers vs. some inline sql (eeek) requiring lots of db round trips is up to you but let's get it in perspective here, the aforementioned is the BASIC query yours is a little errrrm... verbose.